# How to calculate the similarity window in a tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensor with shape (None, 3) `a`, and a step size `k=2`, I want to calculate the cosine similarity vector of each element and its left 2 elements and right 2 elements, if none, compare with [0, 0, 0], output will be with shape of `(None, k*2)`
For example:

```
input:
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[4,5,6],[0,0,0],[3,4,5],[1,1,1]]
k = 2

output:
    [
    [0, 0, 0.9746318, 0.9746318], #cosine([1,2,3], [0,0,0]),cosine([1,2,3], [0,0,0]), cosine([1,2,3], [4,5,6]), cosine([1,2,3], [4,5,6]) 
    [0, 0.9746318, 1, 0 ] 
    [0.9746318, 1, 0, 0.9992205] #cosine([1,2,3], [4,5,6]), cosine([4,5,6], [4,5,6]),cosine([4,5,6], [0,0,0]),cosine([4,5,6], [3,4,5])
    [0,0,0,0]
    [0.9992205,0, 0.97979593, 0]
    [0, 0.97979593, 0, 0]
    ]

a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 3], name="input_placeholder_a")
         name="input_placeholder_b")
normalize_a = tf.nn.l2_normalize(a, -1)
....
```

Comment: Is `k` known at graph definition time or is it a placeholder with value defined through `feed_dict`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know `k` while you are constructing the graph, this is one way to do it:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 3])
k = 2
# Number of input vectors
n = tf.shape(a)[0]
# Normalize
a_norm = tf.math.l2_normalize(a, axis=-1)
# Add zero vectors at beginning and end
a_norm_pad = tf.pad(a_norm, [[k, k], [0, 0]])
# Build array of multiplied vectors
b = []
# From k before to k after
for i in range(0, 2 * k + 1):
    # Skip self
    if i == k: continue
    # Take window of vectors
    b.append(tf.slice(a_norm_pad, [i, 0], [n, -1]))
# Stack windows
b = tf.stack(b, axis=1)
# Dot product
r = tf.reduce_sum(tf.expand_dims(a_norm, 1) * b, axis=-1)
# Test
with tf.Session() as sess:
    v = sess.run(r, feed_dict={a: [[1, 2, 3],
                                   [4, 5, 6],
                                   [4, 5, 6],
                                   [0, 0, 0],
                                   [3, 4, 5],
                                   [1, 1, 1]]})
    print(v)
```

Output:

```
[[0.         0.         0.9746318  0.9746318 ]
 [0.         0.9746318  1.         0.        ]
 [0.9746318  1.         0.         0.9992205 ]
 [0.         0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.9992205  0.         0.97979593 0.        ]
 [0.         0.97979593 0.         0.        ]]
```

EDIT: Here is the same thing but with dynamic `k` value. As far as I know, there is currently no good way to create sliding windows, so you could use a loop to create the `b` array, then the rest would be the same.

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Starts as before
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 3])
k = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[])
a_shape = tf.shape(a)
n = a_shape[0]
d = a_shape[1]
a_norm = tf.math.l2_normalize(a, axis=-1)
a_norm_pad = tf.pad(a_norm, [[k, k], [0, 0]])
# Build second array in a TensorFlow loop
b = tf.TensorArray(a.dtype, size=1, dynamic_size=True,
                   element_shape=[None, 3], clear_after_read=True)
def build_b(i, b):
    # Pick before or after self
    idx = tf.cond(i < k, lambda: i, lambda: i + 1)
    # Add window
    b = b.write(i, tf.slice(a_norm_pad, [idx, 0], [n, -1]))
    return i + 1, b
# Loop and collect
_, b = tf.while_loop(lambda i, b: i < 2 * k, build_b, [0, b])
b = b.stack()
# Fix axes
b = tf.transpose(b, [1, 0, 2])
# Continues as before
r = tf.reduce_sum(tf.expand_dims(a_norm, 1) * b, axis=-1)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    v = sess.run(r, feed_dict={a: [[1, 2, 3],
                                   [4, 5, 6],
                                   [4, 5, 6],
                                   [0, 0, 0],
                                   [3, 4, 5],
                                   [1, 1, 1]],
                               k: 2})
    print(v)
    # Same output as before
```

Answer (score 3):

Try it:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

a_tf = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 3], name="input_placeholder_a")
k_tf = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, name="input_placeholder_b")

result =  tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32,size=1,dynamic_size=True,clear_after_read=False)
# append [0,0,0] at begin and end
a_tf_new = tf.concat([tf.zeros(shape=(k_tf,a_tf.shape[1])),a_tf,tf.zeros(shape=(k_tf,a_tf.shape[1]))],axis=0)
def cond(i,result):
    return i< tf.shape(a_tf)[0]
def body(i,result):
    current_vetor = tf.expand_dims(a_tf_new[i+k_tf,:],0)
    near_vetor = tf.concat([a_tf_new[i:i +k_tf,:],a_tf_new[i+k_tf+1:i + 2*k_tf+1,:]],0)
    # dot product
    similarity = tf.reduce_sum(current_vetor * near_vetor, axis=-1)
    # 1e-8 is used to prevent dividing by 0.
    similarity /= tf.norm(current_vetor, axis=-1) * tf.norm(near_vetor, axis=-1)+ 1e-8
    result = result.write(i, similarity)
    return i+1,result
i = tf.constant(0)
_,result = tf.while_loop(cond, body, [i,result])
result = result.stack()

a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[4,5,6],[0,0,0],[3,4,5],[1,1,1]])
k=2
with tf.Session()as sess:
    a_value = sess.run(result,feed_dict={a_tf:a,k_tf:k})
    print(a_value)

[[0.        0.        0.9746318 0.9746318]
 [0.        0.9746318 1.        0.       ]
 [0.9746318 1.        0.        0.9992205]
 [0.        0.        0.        0.       ]
 [0.9992205 0.        0.9797959 0.       ]
 [0.        0.9797959 0.        0.       ]]
```